# Moving files with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, jpeg

I have 30 folders, one for each travel group with 10 subfolders each, each subfolder corresponds to an activity.Some pictures dont match with the group, so i have a list of the pictures that dont match.

Im using this batch to move the jpgs from the folders but it's putting them all together. is there any way that the batch creates a folder with the name of the folder it's been moved from?

```
for /r "originfolder" %%# in (*) do findstr "%%~nx#" "filelist.txt"&&move "%%#" "destinyfolder"

PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a few more lines. There are a few different ways, this being one of them.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd "originfolder"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("filelist.txt") do for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s "%%a" 2^>nul') do (
    set "filepath=%%~dpi"
    set "filepath=!filepath:~0,-1!"
    for %%f in (!filepath!) do set "destpath=%%~nxf"
    mkdir "C:\Full path to\destinypath\!destpath!"
    move "%%~a" "C:\Full path to\destinypath\!destpath!"
)
popd
```

simply get the path of the file, then use the last name of the path (folder where file exists) and create that folder name in your destination path, before moving the file.

Note, this is untested code, so please use a test scenario before attempting this in production.

Comment: I Tried this and it  only created the folder but it's not moving the files on the list to each folder.

Maybe I did something wrong, the code I used whas this one

Comment: setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd "C:\Users\AGUSTIN\Desktop\prueba12\COCHE 12"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("C:\Users\AGUSTIN\Desktop\prueba12\lista12.txt") do for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s "%%a" 2^>nul') do (
    set "filepath=%%~dpi"
    set "filepath=!filepath:~0,-1!"
    for %%f in (!filepath!) do set "destpath=%%~nxf"
    mkdir "C:\Users\AGUSTIN\Desktop\prueba12\DEPURADAS COCHE 12\!destpath!"
    move "%%~a" "C:\Users\AGUSTIN\Desktop\prueba12\DEPURADAS COCHE 12\!destpath!\"
)
popd

Comment: Change the move line to this and show me a screenshot of the run. `echo move "%%~fa" "C:\Full path to\destinypath\!destpath!"`